# Cannot install mcrypt with homebrew and php7.4

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, mcrypt

OS: macOS 11 (big sur)

Homebrew: 2.5.12

PEAR Version: 1.10.12

I just upgraded the php on my mac from php7.1 to php7.4 with homebrew (brew install php@7.4).

Then, when I try to install mcrypt extension, I got the error:

```
configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/mcrypt/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config --with-mcrypt' failed
```

Here is what I did:

1. brew isntall mcrypt
2. install the pecl
3. sudo pecl install mcrypt -- The error goes here.

What I tried:

1. Located the mcrypt.h and put manually the file to the several locations (based on the php-config), not work.
2. Cleaned the brew and reinstall/relink the mcrypt(libmcrypt), not work.
3. Removed the legacy mcrypt files of the old brew version.

Comment: Any success with this? Having the same problem.

Comment: I gave up the installing php7.4 with homebrew. Finally got my dev env with MAMP Pro.

Answer (score 29):

I ran into the same problem. So after installing libmcrypt with `brew install mcrypt` it seems like configure is not able to resolve the path to mcrypt.h automatically. It also does not work to specify the CPPFLAGS or giving the homebrew include path.

But I found a solution that works for me by giving pecl the install location of mcrypt in the Homebrew Cellar. This is what the following code does automatically:

`pecl install mcrypt <<<"$(ls -d $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/mcrypt/* | tail -1)"`

Comment: Thank you co much! It works like a magic. On my Mac OS Catalina with php 7.4 installed by homebrew.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! I tried a lot and this solved it for me on Mac OS Monterey with M1.

Answer (score 2):

if you using **brew** try this :

1.**Unistall existing php** then Install shivammathur/php

add shivammathur php

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

change php version with you needed (5.6 or 7.2 or 7.4 or 8.1 or next version)

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

2.Install shivammathur/extensions it s will add extension to php
then

```
brew tap shivammathur/extensions

brew install shivammathur/extensions/mcrypt@7.4
```

then you install mcrypt with same version as php version

```
brew install mcrypt@7.4
```

then restart httpd

```
brew services restart httpd
```

Ref :

https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the configure command can't find the libmcrypt installed by homebrew

You can

1. Download the source code of mcrypt-1.0.4, then cd in the folder
2. run "phpize"
3. run "./configure --with-mcrypt=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mcrypt/2.6.8",  you can change the path here with your path for homebrew lib
4. run "make && make install"
5. add extension=mcrypt.so to your config file

ps: Use `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"` to locate your php configure file

Answer (score 0):

in case of an error on **macOS** use the complete path in php.ini like:

```
extension="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.9/pecl/20210902/mcrypt.so"
```